# I cannot get this .sql file to run successfully in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, syntax

MySQL CMD Client will run this file but get half way through and complain my syntax is wrong i have looked over and changed bits in it all day but just cannot find the issue.

I know again its probably a very easily answered question but after looking at it all day its time for a fresh pair of eyes to have a look for me. Please help!

```
DROP DATABASE FIFAWC2010;

CREATE DATABASE FIFAWC2010;

USE FIFAWC2010;

CREATE TABLE VENUE(
    VENUE_ID CHAR(3),
    LOC_COORDS VARCHAR(50),
    CITY VARCHAR(20),
    VENUE_NAME VARCHAR(20),
    MAX_CAPACITY NUMERIC(9),
    PRIMARY KEY(VENUE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE REFEREE(
    REF_ID CHAR(10),
    REF_FNAME VARCHAR(20),
    REF_SNAME VARCHAR(20),
    NATIONALITY VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(REF_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE MATCH(
    MATCH_ID CHAR(11),
    VENUE_ID CHAR(3),
    MATCH_DATE DATE,
    KICK_OFF TIME,
    FINAL_SCORE VARCHAR(7),
    REF_ID CHAR(10),
    VENUE_ATTEN NUMERIC(9),
    PRIMARY KEY(MATCH_ID,VENUE_ID) REFERENCES VENUE(VENUE_ID),

);

CREAT TABLE GROUP(
    GROUP_ID CHAR(1),
    MATCH_ID VARCHAR(28),
    PRIMARY KEY(GROUP_ID),

);

CREATE TABLE COUNTRY(
    COUNTRY_ID VARCHAR(20), 
    GROUP_ID CHAR(1),
    PRIMARY KEY(COUNTRY_ID),

);

CREATE TABLE PLAYER(
    PLAYER_ID CHAR(10), 
    PLAYER_FNAME VARCHAR(20), 
    PLAYER_SNAME VARCHAR(20), 
    POSITION VARCHAR(10), 
    MATCH_ID CHAR(11),
    COUNRTY_ID VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(PLAYER_ID),

);

COMMIT;
```

Thank you! :) Ash.

**UPDATE:
Sorry i pasted the wrong code, this is the code i am using and having issues with:**

```
 DROP DATABASE FIFAWC2010;

    CREATE DATABASE FIFAWC2010;

    USE FIFAWC2010;

    CREATE TABLE VENUE(
        VENUE_ID CHAR(3),
        LOC_COORDS VARCHAR(50),
        CITY VARCHAR(20),
        VENUE_NAME VARCHAR(20),
        MAX_CAPACITY NUMERIC(9),
        PRIMARY KEY(VENUE_ID)
    );

    CREATE TABLE REFEREE(
        REF_ID CHAR(10),
        REF_FNAME VARCHAR(20),
        REF_SNAME VARCHAR(20),
        NATIONALITY VARCHAR(20),
        PRIMARY KEY(REF_ID)
    );

    CREATE TABLE MATCH(
        MATCH_ID CHAR(11),
        VENUE_ID CHAR(3),
        MATCH_DATE DATE,
        KICK_OFF TIME,
        FINAL_SCORE VARCHAR(7),
        REF_ID CHAR(10),
        VENUE_ATTEN NUMERIC(9),
        PRIMARY KEY(MATCH_ID,VENUE_ID) REFERENCES VENUE(VENUE_ID),
        FOREIGN KEY(REF_ID) REFERENCES REFEREE(REF_ID)
    );

    CREAT TABLE GROUP(
        GROUP_ID CHAR(1),
        MATCH_ID VARCHAR(28),
        PRIMARY KEY(GROUP_ID),
        FOREIGN KEY(MATCH_ID) REFERENCES MATCH(MATCH_ID)
    );

    CREATE TABLE COUNTRY(
        COUNTRY_ID VARCHAR(20), 
        GROUP_ID CHAR(1),
        PRIMARY KEY(COUNTRY_ID),
        FOREIGN KEY(GROUP_ID) REFERENCES GROUP(GROUP_ID)
    );

    CREATE TABLE PLAYER(
        PLAYER_ID CHAR(10), 
        PLAYER_FNAME VARCHAR(20), 
        PLAYER_SNAME VARCHAR(20), 
        POSITION VARCHAR(10), 
        MATCH_ID CHAR(11),
        COUNRTY_ID VARCHAR(20),
        PRIMARY KEY(PLAYER_ID),
        FOREIGN KEY(COUNTRY_ID) REFERENCES COUNTRY(COUNTRY_ID), 
        FOREIGN KEY(MATCH_ID) REFERENCES MATCH(MATCH_ID)
    );

    COMMIT;
```

I get Error 1064 (42000) 4 times, and its on MATCH, GROUP, (MATCH_ID), (GROUP_ID).

Is this a syntax error with the Primary keys?

Comment: What line does it give as having the error?

Comment: Have you tried feeding the statements one-by-one and localizing the problem precisely this way first?

Comment: I have updated the code to the version i was using, Also yeah i have tried but cant find the error i think its based arounf the Foreign and Primary keys because all of the other variable seem to go in fine but i dont see where i have gone wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess : having a `,` on the last line of a list... like this one:

```
PRIMARY KEY(MATCH_ID,VENUE_ID) REFERENCES VENUE(VENUE_ID),
```

change to

```
PRIMARY KEY(MATCH_ID,VENUE_ID) REFERENCES VENUE(VENUE_ID)
```

you have 4 of them.

Comment: +1: But it's probably not intended that two columns both reference the same foreign key column

Comment: @OMG - I agree, I was looking for syntax errors, not logical ones.

Comment: OMG - What do you mean? Where i have used the same name? For example FOREIGN KEY(GROUP_ID) REFERENCES GROUP(GROUP_ID)?

Comment: @Ash -- saying key of match and venue => venue does not make sense -- you mean venue => venue, right?

Comment: I was trying to use a composite key, using VENUE_ID from the VENUE as well as the MATCH_ID from the MATCH table. I thought thats how you would reference a foreign key but as a primary key, if you see what i mean?

Comment: @Ash : yes I see what you are trying to do, I don't know the syntax for it, but I doubt this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix the error my self, it would seem that MATCH and GROUP are actually keywords that MySQL / SQL uses and cannot be used as the names of my tables, I installed MySQL WorkBench and it will underline errors for you.

Also to create a composite key with a Foreign Key, you first create the variable for the data to sit in, use the foreign key syntax to get the data into the variable, then use the usual syntax for a composite key with the Foreign Key variable in place.

Thank you everyone for your help!

Ash.